# How do I require a directory in a node_module?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

To make my `gulpfile.js` easier to read, I put all of my gulp tasks in a `gulp/` directory.  The only thing I now do in my `gulpfile.js` is require in the whole directory like this:

```
var requireDir = require('require-dir');
requireDir('./gulp');
```

An example task file is `default.js'

```
gulp.task('default', function() {
  // Do stuff here
});
```

I now use the same `gulp` stuff in multiple projects, so I create a `npm` module and packaged all of my `gulp` tasks into it.  When I try to change my `gulpfile.js` to point at the directory with the same contenxt in `node_modules` like this:

```
var requireDir = require('require-dir');
requireDir('./node_modules/my-gulp/gulp');
```

it doesn't find any of my tasks.  It is the same directory as before, so why won't it work?  What can I do to pull in multiple `gulp` tasks in this manner?

Comment: Did you install the requireDir package into the new project?

Comment: Yes.  It is installed in the project.